# Select.value property not persisting changes, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a for loop in which I iterate through array and form a `<select>` menu. In every iteration I want to set the selected item in `<select>`. I am changing selected item using `select.value = value`, but it doesn't change the selected item.

When I stepped through google chrome debugger I saw that selected item is being changed temporarily, but when current iteration ends, selected item is changed to first `<option>` for some strange reason. This is the whole code:

```js
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "";
var content = msg.content;
var i;

var list = document.getElementById("list");
// Printing employees
for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {

  list.innerHTML += content[i].firstName +
    " " +
    content[i].lastName +
    " " +
    content[i].email +
    " " +
    content[i].role.rolePriority +
    " ";

  var select = document.createElement("select");

  var option1 = document.createElement("option");
  option1.value = "0";
  option1.text = "Superadmin";
  var option2 = document.createElement("option");
  option2.value = "1";
  option2.text = "Admin";
  var option3 = document.createElement("option");
  option3.value = "2";
  option3.text = "User";
  select.appendChild(option1);
  select.appendChild(option2);
  select.appendChild(option3);
  select.id = "select_" + content[i].email;

  select.value = content[i].role.rolePriority;
  list.appendChild(select);
  list.innerHTML += '<a href="#" onClick="updateRole(\'' + content[i].email + '\')">update role</a> </br>';
```

**Edit**

What I found out is that select changes `select.value` propery (and changes the selected item) when I use `innerHTML` on the `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it renders the code after your for loop, 
so in js it was selected but not in the html.

To select the default value you should perform other for loop of the content array and there select the value.

```js
 document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "";
    var element={firstName: "mario",lastName: "rossi",email: "test@test.ts",role:{rolePriority:2}};
    var element2={firstName: "mario2",lastName: "rossi",email: "test2@test.ts",role:{rolePriority:1}};
    var element3={firstName: "mario3",lastName: "rossi",email: "test3@test.ts",role:{rolePriority:2}};
    var content = [];
    content.push(element);
    content.push(element2);
    content.push(element3);
    var i;
    
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    // Printing employees
    for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    
      list.innerHTML += content[i].firstName +
        " " +
        content[i].lastName +
        " " +
        content[i].email +
        " " +
        content[i].role.rolePriority +
        " ";
    
      var select = document.createElement("select");
    
      var option1 = document.createElement("option");
      option1.value = "0";
      option1.text = "Superadmin";
      var option2 = document.createElement("option");
      option2.value = "1";
      option2.text = "Admin";
      var option3 = document.createElement("option");
      option3.value = "2";
      option3.text = "User";
      select.appendChild(option1);
      select.appendChild(option2);
      select.appendChild(option3);
      select.id = "select_" + content[i].email;
    
      
      list.appendChild(select);

      
      list.innerHTML += '<a href="#" onClick="updateRole(\'' + content[i].email + '\')">update role</a> </br>';
    }
    for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("select_" + content[i].email).value=content[i].role.rolePriority;
    }
```

```html
<div id="list">
</div>
```